# Choose second radio button using capybara

Tags: selenium, capybara

From the following html how can i choose the second radio button .In the page load first radio button is selected when i use the following code

page.choose('#PPRINT')

```
<div id="printOpns" class="span6">
<div class="row"> <div class="span2" align="center">
<input id="Print" class="radio" type="radio" checked="" value="EPrint" name="printO"></div>
</div>
<div class="row"><div class="span2" align="center">
<input id="PPRINT" class="radio" type="radio" value="FPrint" name="printO">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Capybara API for the [choose method](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#choose-instance_method) says "Find a radio button and mark it as checked. The radio button can be found via name, id or label text." This means that the text that is supplied to the `choose` method must match the name, id or label of the radio button.

`choose` does not support css-selectors. Therefore, when you do:

```
page.choose('#PPRINT')
```

Capybara is looking for a name, id or label that equals "#PPRINT".

You want to do (ie no "#"):

```
page.choose('PPRINT')
```